# Time spent in accepted state by a YARN job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

How do I check for how much time a Spark job spends in the accepted state before resources are allocated to it? Can I check it in YARN UI or does Spark releases some telemetry for this? We can see the state while the job is running, but how do we see for an old job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for state change in yarn logs

```
<timestamp> INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_XXX
<timestamp>  INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_XXXX (state: ACCEPTED)
```

then,u may capture the time diff when state changed.

Answer (score 0):

i checked the yarn logs through yarn logs --applicationId  command, but it's not showing application state anywhere